# Perform if in mysql or php

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, if-statement

I have 3 tables :

-User

-SuperUser

-SpecialUser

`SpecialUser` and `SuperUser` are extensions of the `User` table. Let's say that `User` table has {`name`, `email`}, `SuperUser` has {`idUser`, `superPower`} and `specialUser` has {`idUser`, `hairColor`}.

Of course a `SpecialUser` and a `SuperUser` have a `name` and `email` from the user table. This means that a User can be a `SuperUser` or a `SpecialUser`.

My question is how do I perform a query that gets all the info of a user (I don't know before the query if he is a specialUser or SuperUser).

I thought about 2 methods :

-Putting a column "userType" (0 : he is specialUser, 1 : he is superUser) in the user table

With this method, should I do a MySQL query with IF inside ? (What would be the query). Or should I do simple query (getting the user table alone) then in PHP I do a if and query the right table (super or special table)

OR

-Not putting any column and doing a MySQL query with 2 joins on the id of the user (technically one of the 2 joins won't return anything)

Which one should be used ? (I care about speed performance, less about memory - Let's say that the tables have over 1 million rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would do this is in pseudo-sql:

```
Select * from user
left outer join superuser
left outer join specialuser
```

And return everything. If superuser's fields are not null, then in the PHP you can operate on that, same for specialuser. And this gives you two advantages:

1) You don't need a field to say what kind of user the user is anymore, the contents of the join will tell you.

2) You can have a user be a superuser and a specialuser at once, if you wished. (And if you didn't want that to happen, you can prevent it using a constraint or similar)

Answer (score 1):

To do this without branching might be tricky, though I have an idea; since you said memory is not a problem, 
but performance is.

First off make a column in the `User` table and call it `userType` like you suggested and store the contents of the table name followed by the table columns in a parse-able string like:

> (SuperUser/SpecialUser), ("idUser, superPower"/"idUser, hairColor")

Example:

> "SuperUser, idUser, superPower" //for a SuperUser

In psuedo code:

```
SELECT `userType` FROM `usersTable` WHERE name = [put var here]
Let the returned value be valRet
parse the valRet into an array... //the first value is the table name, the remaining values are column names
make a second sql query based on the array
```

Performance wise I believe this is good because there is **no branching**. However, I'm not sure what kind of performance hit you would take on the string parsing. Try benchmarking it on a few thousand queries to see.

//Also check out the answer to a similar question here:
[Using an IF Statement in a MySQL SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444570/if-statement-in-mysql-select-query)

Comment: @BabyAzerty conceptually yes... but it's not difficult to program instead of storing 1 or 0 in `userType`, you're storing a string containing the name of the related table, and the column names in that table to pull... However, I can't guarantee it would be faster than the other answer; it **MIGHT** be, but I haven't benchmarked it.