# MYSQL Where IF statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I want to select all the entrees in a MYSQL database if a certain value in a row - another value is greater than a certain number. I want something like this but that actually works, is it possible?

```
$str = date("d/m/y");
$donetime = strtotime($str);

$currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `entree` WHERE IF(`Uploaded`-$donetime <= 604800)  ");
```

Is it possible to have something like this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444570/using-an-if-statement-in-a-mysql-select-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `SELECT` all rows `WHERE` `Uploaded-$donetime <= 604800` then you should write the following.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `entree` 
WHERE `Uploaded`-$donetime <= 604800
```

You might want to read up on SQL.